# Why this range attribute in mvc does not give me right answer.?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to apply range attribute on my class field like this.

```
 [Range(typeof(Int32), "1","999", ErrorMessage = "Must be a Number between 1  and 999")]

 public long? FieldName{ get; set; }
```

But it doesn't validate the range as I was expecting. It is supposed to validate range between 1 and 999. 
How to resolve this issue.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine (if you enter 0 or 1000, an error message will be displayed. What are you expecting to happen? (Note you can also write it simply as `[Range(1, 999, ErrorMessage = "Must ...")]`

Comment: I was expecting positive natural number range between 1 and 999 excluding decimal number. Data annotation above and the one you wrote in comment both are accepting decimal number.

Comment: A `Range` attribute only limits the range. (a value such as `9.09` is within the range so its valid) But you will get a server side error because its not valid for typeof `long`

Answer (score 1):

Try this..........

[Range(typeof(Int32), "1", "999", ErrorMessage = "Must be a positive natural Number between 1  and 999")]
        [RegularExpression("^[0-9]{1,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Must be a positive natural Number between 1  and 999")]
        public long? FieldName { get; set; }